# Set new array value in article Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I need to create a new array in article joomla, for example: When i use in php.

```
<pre>
<?php
  print_r ($this);
?>
</pre>
```

In this case i get all values in arcticle, so, i need to add a new variable, a Array (the field is in article.xml and show in when i edit it), how can add a new value & array or variable into article joomla 3.x

I know how retrieve the data to manipulate later, i new just how can set more data into article.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use plugin hooks of the content component to manipulate the variables added in the xml descriptor file, there is a well documented page for J!2.5 that details the process but you will get the idea to do it in J!3: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component